# Phase of grid current is not varying in the simple RL circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, passive-networks, power-factor-correction, phase-shift

I am trying to implement the following circuit:

[image]

Circuit parameters are as follows:

- R1 = 2 ohms
- L1 = 10mH
- V_inverter = 28.175V (peak)
- V_grid = 200V (peak)

I want the grid current to vary in full range with respect to the grid voltage. I want the grid current to vary from a lagging --> zero--> leading phase with respect to the grid voltage.

I am trying to achieve this by varying the phase of the V_inverter from -360,+360 degrees. The result that I'm getting is as follows:

[image]

The I_grid magnitude is adjusting itself by increasing/decreasing as per need, but the phase difference between I_grid and V_grid is locked at around 108 degrees and is not varying. How can I achieve the phase variation that I need?

Note that only V_inverter parameters can be controlled. R1, L1, and V_grid are constant variables and they cannot be altered.

Answer (score 0):

The phase angle of the current is set by the R-L components, not by the phase of the supply voltage. Varying the phase of \$V_{inverter}\$ will simply shift the phase of the load by an equivalent amount.

We can see this from the maths:

$$Z_{RL} = R + jX_L = \sqrt{R^2 + X_L^2}\ \angle\ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{X_L}{R}\right) = r\ \angle\ \theta_Z$$

$$\bar{V}_{RL} = \bar{I}Z$$
$$V_{RL}\ \angle\ \theta_V = I\ \angle\ \theta_I \times r\ \angle\ \theta_Z = Ir\ \angle\ (\theta_I + \theta_Z)$$

Given that \$\theta_Z\$ is fixed (based on \$R\$ and \$X_L\ (L)\$, then changing the angle of the voltage \$\theta_V\$ must change the phase of the current through the R-L circuit, and hence current through the load by an equivalent amount.

You can do the same thing in reverse to work out that if the load impedance is fixed, then changing the current phase of the load will change the load voltage by an equivalent amount. Hence changing the source phase has no impact on changing leading/lagging phase difference.

The only way to change the whether the current is leading or lagging is to change the load in such a way to make this happen. You could for example do this by varying \$X_L\$ from an inductive reactance to a capacitive one. However given your \$R\$ and \$X_L\$ are fixed, you will need to change the source parameters in a way that changes the \$V_{inverter}\$ and \$I_{inverter}\$ relationship (e.g. by adding another reactive element in series/parallel).

Comment: Can you please define the variables that you have used as per the circuit above? Using too many variables like $\theta_{i}$, $\theta_{v}$, $I$, etc makes the answer more confusing. Also, load angle $\theta_{z}$ is atan(XL/R), not the other way around.